# Why isn't my invalid WCF message being logged?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I've got a WCF client communicating with a WCF service using `[DataContract]` types, and I'm getting a serialization error:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error
>   while trying to deserialize parameter http://www.example.com/2007/09/Example:ExampleResult.
>   The InnerException message was 'Deserialized object with reference id 'i3' not found in
>   stream.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Normally, I'd simply crank up the tracing and see exactly what happened, but in this case, I can't get the offending (response) message to appear in the log.

My configuration looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    ... (more stuff)
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
        maxMessagesToLog="10000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="81920000" />
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="wcf_listener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
            <listeners>
                <add name="wcf_listener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="wcf_listener" initializeData="tracelog.svclog"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" />
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

In the resulting log file, I get the outbound message logged, and then the exception logged. I never see the incoming message. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try specifying 'Order' parameter in your DataMember attribute. If, for some reason, elements get mixed up during serialization/deserialization process, this is supposed to take care of it. For instance: `[DataMember(Order=1)] public string Something { get; set; }` It might help.

Comment: I'm not looking to solve the deserialization error (indeed, it's already solved...), I'm looking to solve the logging problem.

Comment: Did you try changing the `switchValue` to `"All"` and see if the message is then logged?

Comment: I didn't. I don't know if it would have helped.

Comment: switchValue has no affect on the message logging source: 
"The switchValue attribute of a source is only valid for tracing. If you specify a switchValue attribute for the System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging trace source as follows, it has no effect." 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the problem related to your flooded data between the service and the client.

Please refer to my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102297/httpclient-posting-byte-to-wcf-service-produces-error-the-maximum-array-lengt/11190257#11190257)

Comment: Do you have any evidence for that? The messages were not large, and there was only one.