# HttpClient posting byte[] to WCF service produces error: The maximum array length quota (16384) or the maximum items

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I have a WCF service that can accept a `byte[]`. I'm creating a client using `HttpClient` and am receiving the following error. I've read online that you have to set the `readerQuotas` on both the server and the client, but how do I set these settings on the `HttpClient`?

#### Error:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type RTM.API.Resources.UGCRequest. The maximum array length quota (16384) or the maximum items in object graph quota has been exceeded while reading XML data. These quotas may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas or the MaxItemsInObjectGraph setting.

#### Server Config:

```xml
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
            <standardEndpoint name="DirectoryEndpoint"/>
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
        <service name="API.Service.UGCService" behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint contract="API.Service.UGCService" kind="webHttpEndpoint" endpointConfiguration="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BigHttpBinding"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483644"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BigHttpBinding" transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
                <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

#### Client code:

```cs
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(apiPath))
            {
                using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, finalUrl))
                {
                    request.Headers.Accept.AddString("application/json");
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", sb.ToString());

                    if (method == "POST" || method == "PUT")
                    {
                        if (requestBody.Count() == 0)
                            request.Headers.ContentLength = 0;
                        else
                        {
                            request.Content = HttpContent.Create(APM6.Utils.Serialize(requestBody), "application/json");
                        }
                    }

                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.Send(request))
                    {
                        return response.Content.ReadAsString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just as an off-topic, I've been struggling with WCF for 6 months now and I would **not** recommend using it to exposing a JSON interface (its lots of intricacies doesn't pay the effort). If you want to stick with Microsoft technologies and can evaluate an alternative, take a look at WebAPI.

Answer (score 3):

`readerQuotas` is a set of additional constrains that WCF implements to provide protection from denial of service (DOS) attacks.

`HttpClient` does not implement that protection so you do not need to worry about extra client  configuration.

You see that error because `<readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" />` for some reason is not applied to your server endpoint. You may use `svcutil.exe` or `wcftestclient.exe` to prove that.

Try to generate config file using these tools and you will probably see `<readerQuotas maxArrayLength="16384" />` in that config file. That means that server part did not apply extended value to `maxArrayLength`.

If that is true, play with server side config or code to make sure that configuration is applied.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="namespace1.namespace1Behavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph ="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="mybehavior">
      <transactedBatching maxBatchSize="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="namespace1.namespace1Behavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph ="2147483647"/>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the only setting that you need on the client is `MaxResponseContentBufferSize`.

However, your problem has occurred during deserialization on the server.  You might need to add `maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"` as the binding parameters

This still does not seem to perfectly correspond to the error message.  Make very sure that the service behavior corresponds to the configuration file shown in the question and not to some different copy.

Comment: I added maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" to the binding and am still getting the error. Is the error definitely happening on the server? Any other ideas?

Comment: @TroyBarlow - Yes, request deserialization is happening on the server.  I think you are shadowing some of the posted server config programmatically or using `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` in your server side code (getting the default `MaxItemsInObjectGraph` of 65536).  Note that when serializing or deserializing arrays, every array entry counts as a separate object.  If this is the case, set `MaxItemsInObjectGraph` at the attribute as well.